# Оффлайн изменение сборки Visual Studio 2019. Добавление языка

Tags: сборка, visual-studio-2019

Скачал, установил, активировал VS 2019 из сборки которая предостовляется на работе(все скачивается с сервера организации, а не microsoft). Проблема в том, что пакет языка только Англ, скачал русский пакет, как его теперь аккуратно добавить в сборку?

**update**

ПК в оффлайне, изолирован. Сборка предостовляется организацией. Установщик скачивает не с сервера майрософт, а с рабочего, но русский пакет установщик пытается скачать с серверов макрософт(недоработка). Вопрос был в том, как скачать русский пакет отдельно и добавить его в VS 2019

**update 2**
Файл не должен быть .exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поиск Windows Server 2019 LangPack, 
или https://www.heidoc.net/php/myvsdump_name.php?family=Windows%20Server%202019&name=Windows%20Server%202019%20Language%20Pack
Выполнить команду lpksetup для установки

Comment: это оказалось не так прозначно и легко как я думал. Думал процесс как в Python,где почти все можно добавить легко. Скачал,  добавив командой в консоли Если вариантов больше не будет, зачту вам ответ, ибо он верный, хоть мне и не подходит.